# How do I find Queen Endregas?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm having problems with luring out the Queen Endregas to complete the Endrega Contract mission. I understand from reading up on the lore that Endrega queens only appear when I find their cocoons **and set fire to them**. However, when I use the spell that seems to set things on fire, *Igni*, on the cocoons, nothing happens. How do I light the cocoons on fire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to light the cocoons on fire.  Beating them to death with your sword is sufficient.  Make sure you open them up first.   In order to be able to open them, however, you must have the knowledge about the Endrega.  You can accomplish this either by killing three of them or buying the book from the dwarf in the nonhuman district who sells books.

Comment: Wait, really? I had beaten them to death but no queens emerged...I guess I had been impatient or something and left too soon.

Comment: @Mana - you're probably missing one. There's 3 cocoons for each queen. She only appears when the last one is slain.

Answer (score 10):

As StrixVaria already mentioned, you only need to open each cocoon and hit it with your sword. There are two groups of three cocoons each, destroying all cocoons of a group will spawn one of the Queen Endregas.

I've marked the locations of the six Endrega cocoons on a map:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the locations. This is a very fun action adventure rpg.